# how to add new dictionary entries from user input

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Writing a Spanish language test program which prints a Spanish phrase and the user inputs the English translation which is graded as correct or wrong.
The problem: at the start, I want the user to be able to add new phrases to the test (add new dictionary entries, like dictionary.append or something) from user input. These entries should be permanently saved for future quizzing. My current code encounters error "dictionary changed size during iteration". How can I modify the code such that the user can add their own new phrases to the test?

```
spanish = {"hola":"hello", "hasta luego":"see you later",
           "como se llama?": "what is your name"}
correct = 0
wrong = 0
print("type addpair at any time to add dictionary entry")
print(" ")

for key in spanish.keys():
    print(key)
    x = input()
    if x == "addpair": 
        print("key: ")
        key = str(input())
        print("value: ")
        value = str(input())
        spanish.update({key:value})
    elif x == spanish[key]:
        print("correct!")
        correct += 1
    else:
        print("wrong!")
        wrong += 1
    print(" ")

total = correct + wrong
print(correct,"/",total)
```

Comment: Can you explain how your program is supposed to run? The way I see it, it prints one key, then asks if you want to add a pair. Regardless of whether you want to add or not, it then prints the next key, and so on. The problem here is you are adding to the dictionary while iterating over it. You should populate your dictionary, then when they are done, print it.

Comment: I would also like to let you know that with the current way your program is written, a user can effectively skip a question by choosing to add a pair.

Comment: I am new to coding so thanks for your suggestions! I did what you said, rearranged the code so they can populate the dictionary with additional questions first, then print it. Any idea how to make the entries permanent? They disappear as soon as the program is restarted. I am trying to make permanent entries.

Comment: The initial questions in your dictionary are hard-coded so they stay between program runs. The user inputted ones will always clear when you restart the program. To keep them, you would have to save the dictionary to a file on exit. You would also have to read that dictionary from the file when starting. You can look into converting the dictionary into a JSON and saving it into a text file.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Will work on that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ouroboros please upvote the comment that you found helpful. And edit your question, so it easier for someone to understand.

Comment: I am reputation 13, currently unable to upvote. Will upvote when able. Also edited question.